# Joomla sql transaction in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, foreach

What do you think about this block of code? I wan't to execute all queries from array.

```
foreach($sql_array as $sql) {
     try {

        $this->_db->transactionStart();
        $this->_db->setQuery((string)$sql)->execute();
        $this->_db->transactionCommit();

     } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_db->transactionRollback();
        JErrorPage::render($e);
     }
}
```

Or should I move `$this->_db->transactionStart();` before `foreach` statement?

Comment: You are asking for an opinion instead of an answer. This is  Q&A site for specific problems, if you want someone to look at your code check out [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).